# How to contact ASP Mvc when performing a web API operation from a mobile phone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have panel for admin that wrote with ASP Mvc
also i have mobile service that wrote with web API
How to contact ASP Mvc when performing a web API operation from a mobile phone,
for example,when user use mobile for submit order,i want admin see new order without refreshing the page

Comment: SignalR might be a useful tool for this. Or Server Sent Events. Or more naively, a simple AJAX request repeatedly polling the server for updates.

Comment: i worked with signalr many yearse ago 
but i am looking for best peractice for this,send ajax repeatedly  for get new order is very easy but its not best

Comment: "best practice" is largely a matter of opinion, really. I'd agree the AJAX polling is not usually a great solution because it can be inefficient and lead to performance problems. Your other choices are primarily SignalR or Server-Sent Events. They have different features, different ways of implementing, and potentially different levels of support etc. Use whatever best meets **your** needs (both functional and non-functional).

Comment: ADyson,
Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

SignalR will be the best solution to this without refreshing the page.

SignalR is available as a service in Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/signalr-service/

Comment: I use signalr in asp,but i dont know how config for both my service and my panel